# Set only specific Parameters in DTOs use a mapper

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to set only fixed parameters from DTO. I have 3 Entity (tables) which are connected with FK or PK. So when I am getting data from database using ID of Table A. Jpa will give me All data with its child that's exactly I want.

```
public class AEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "a_id")
private Long aId;
private String name;
private String model;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
private bEntity bentity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_uid")
private cEntity centity;

@JoinColumn(name = "d_id")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<dEntity> d;

}
```

Like this I have B,C,D Entity also. now here I am getting Data by A_id. And created aDTO like:

```
public class aDTO {

private Long a_Id;
@JsonProperty(required=true)
private String name;
@JsonProperty(required=true)
private String model;

    @Valid
    private List<AllbDTO>  bList;

    private List<AllcDTO>  cList;

}
```

And using this code:

```
     {
     Type targetListType = new TypeToken<List<aDTO>>() {                 
     }.getType();
      List<aDTO> aDTOs = mapper.map(AllDAtaByQuery, targetListType);
                return aDTOs ;
}
```

now "AllDAtaByQuery" its an entity object to storedata from query and all are working fine. Its giving me list of a then inner list with b tables data and so on with all field.
Q: Is it possible that I tell mapper to map specific fields i want So i can send response with specific field?
Like b table have 6 fields but I want only 2 fields data in response by using same DTO. so i will use same dto for all other query and manipulate the response according need.

Comment: `mapper`, is an instance of what, exactly?

Comment: its the instance of main Entity table from where I am getting Result

Comment: Please rewrite your post for more clarity...

Comment: I am using ModelMapper here,  currently My GET queries returning all A table data with bList and cList. But I want to return data which have specific fields of bList or cList